# How to get lyrics from Musixmatch

Tags: jquery, musixmatch

I have a webradio and and the player gives me the song name and song artist

I read those two in a jQuery var like this:

```html
<script>
$('#GetLyrics').on('click', function(ev) {
  songArtistTitle.value = jQuery('#artist').text() + ' - '+ jQuery('#title').text() + jQuery('#year').text();
.
.
```

"#artist" and "#title" are 2 divs that are auto updated by the player

the Musixmatch API its going like this:

```txt
http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?apikey=***&q_track=Dire%20straits%20Sultans%20of%20Swing&page_size=10
```

and returns the list of songs with "track_id":3867545,
and then you must get the lyrics with the API

```txt
http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.lyrics.get?track_id=3867545
```

I want to have a button "GetLyrics" and when pressed by the user to have the list of songs from Musixmatch (with `TRACK.SEARCH`)(most of the times it will have only one song) and when the user select the correct song to display the lyrics

Can anyone please help me with the code to read the lyrics from Musixmatch database and display them?
[**my webradio is here**](http://colossusradio.blogspot.gr/)

Comment: don't post your api keys on public websites

Comment: @webnoob I'm too lazy today to edit, besides if you don't bring attention to it they never learn

Answer (score 0):

Lastly, the track you are looking for 3867545 does not have lyrics, 'has_lyrics' param is zero 0.  A track ID that works is: track_id=5850832.